# Symbology created with geometry generators renders murky in print legend

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, geometry-generator

I have a style that makes use of the geometry generator for a wavy line:

[image]

the code is as follows, with units set to `mm`

```
wave($geometry,
    6,
    1.5)
    )
```

When I export the map as a vector format (PDF/SVG), the legend gets very murky:

[image]

Exporting as Raster works fine:

[image]

I played around with the settings for PDF export, to no avail. But I realized, this is scale dependent:

[image: 1:100]

[image: 1:1000]

[image: 1:10000]

Is there any fix? Is it possible to mimik another scale for the legend than for the map? Or should I use SVG's to style my layers?